# using OOoWrite, i would like to add custom html elements

Tags: html, macros, openoffice-writer

I have 35 pages list of scientific references. In order to upload them to a webpage, I would like to add custom

fields before and after each reference. I would also like to find italicized text and add  around it.

For instance, I would like this paragraph

Alouf N., 1973. Biotope et description de *Niphargus altagahizi* n. sp., Amphipode Gammaridé souterrain du Liban, International Journal of Speleology 5: 49-61.

to look like:

`<p class="cite">Alouf N., 1973. Biotope et description de <em>Niphargus altagahizi</em> n. sp., Amphipode Gammaridé souterrain du Liban, International Journal of Speleology 5: 49-61.</p>`

Any suggestions how to do this in OOoWriter macros perhaps, or any other application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a macro. I have just saved the file to .xml and used Find/Replace to add the desired tags. Thank you Stack Overflow for the tips!